# Start -> end | stop | finish?

Tags: naming-conventions

I'm programming a class and I was wondering which pair of methods makes more sense for describing a process cycle:

```
start() -> stop()
start() -> end()
start() -> finish()
```

Basically these methods will be called before and after executing a task.

What I'm asking is in English (specifically in programming - any language -) which pair is more common to see?

Sorry I'm not native speaker so I would like to hear which one people prefer.

If it is not clear enough please let me know to fix it or add more info.

Thank you in advance.

**Update:**

The intention of the methods is to call for any "user functions" before and after running the task. For the task itself would do nothing special.

Comment: I decided for now to go with onStarted() and onCompleted(). Thank you everyone for your answers.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### It depends.

- If calling the method will abort the task or stop it early, call it `abort()` or `stop()`.
- If calling the method will wait until the task finishes, call it `waitFor()`.
- If calling the method will perform the final steps of the task, call it `finish()`.
- If calling the method will clean up after the task, call it `Dispose()` or `cleanup()`.
  Most languages have a standard name for such a method; use it.
- **Update**: If I understand your situation correctly, I would recommend `OnStarted()` and `OnCompleted()`

Comment: I've also seen Cryptographic hash functions use an `init()`, `update()`, and `final()` when data is passed into the routine in chunks: http://www.rocketaware.com/man/man3/md5.3.htm

Comment: I think it would be more like finish() in your list

Answer (score 15):

Thats a fairly contextual question but generally you could write:

start() -> stop()
begin() -> end()

you could use finish() to clean up and close the program but close() is more used.

Answer (score 2):

`start() and stop()` make most sense to me, but only if the stop() method is actually stopping a task. (First example I think of is Java's Thread class which has start() and stop() methods.)

However, if it's to do some operation after executing the task rather than stopping the task itself, then a better description would be what that method actually does, `closeResources()`, `cleanup()` or so on.

Still somewhat dependant on circumstance, but given update 2, peraps something like `setup() and teardown()`, `init() and completed()` would be more appropriate?

Comment: It completely depends on what the method actually does.

Comment: What do you mean by "user functions?"

Comment: Yes, I have seen setup() as well.. I forgot that one.

Answer (score 2):

Highly subjective and important topic, some interesting points are [here](https://www.yourenglishsuccesstoday.com/english-language-blog/confusing-words-begin-start-end-finish) and [here](https://thegrammarexchange.infopop.cc/topic/fisnish-vs-end-and-start-vs-begin).

`start -> stop` ... start/stop some activity; sometimes a service provided to other components; e.g. *start/stop listening on a socket and processing incoming requests*

`start -> finish` ... start/finish some task, a processing step, or similar; here, the task is **completed in some sense** i.e. it is not aborted or cancelled; e.g. *start iterative model optimization, finish the current iteration and return the result*

`end` goes better with `begin` than with `start` (think Pascal language constructs :-) `begin -> end` is quite interchangeable with `start -> finish`